# why can I put |> on the next line but <| gives a syntax error?

Tags: f#, syntax-error

I can do this:

```
let foo = bar
    |> baz
```

but I get a syntax error when I do this:

```
let foo = bar
    <| baz
```

why?

I also get the syntax error when ever I define my own infix operators and try to use them in this manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, the two operators (as well as any other infix operator) behave the same. When I define `bar` and `baz` and use your example, I get an error in both of the cases. The off-side rule in F# allows you to indent the operator less far from the left, but the column of the arguments has to match:

```
let bar = 1
let baz x = x + 1

let foo1 = bar 
        |> baz

let foo2 = baz 
        <| bar
```

Both of these give an error message:

```
let foo1 = bar 
  |> baz

let foo2 = baz 
  <| bar
```

(Although you may see only the first error, because the F# compiler stops reporting additional errors after syntax error - probably because it cannot guarantee that they will be sensible)

The rules are quite well described in [Code Formatting Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233191.aspx#Y502) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

I did not catch the indentation error because both of the following were working:

```
match r.IsDBNull index  with
| true -> None
| _ -> r.GetValue index
    :?> 'a
    |> Some

let param p =
    db.CreateParameter p
    |> cmd.Parameters.Add
    |> ignore
```

even though I had only hit tab once. Yet I hit tab once here, and it was not correctly indented:

```
let foo2 = proc "getfoo2" 
    <| [ "x",Int32,In;
         "y",String(15),In ]
```

it should have been either of the two:

```
let foo2 = proc "getfoo2" 
         <| [ "x",Int32,In;
              "y",String(15),In ]

let foo2 = 
    proc "getfoo2" 
    <| [ "x",Int32,In;
         "y",String(15),In ]
```

So my misunderstanding was that whitespace didn't matter so long as it was further indented than the line before it. This is not the case.